# Is there a way to use Storyboard with ListView/GridView items?

Tags: c#, uwp

Here is my question:

1. I have a GridView in my UWP app. Each item in the GridView, keeps a button. Like following:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ExampleItems, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="mDataGridView">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Background="OrangeRed" x:Name="rootPanel">
                <Grid Width="155" Height="210" Background="Red" x:Name="myGrid"/>
                <Button x:Name="mOpenDetailButton" Click="mOpenDetailButton_Click" Margin="0, 30, 20,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

2. I also have a pre-defined animation in a Storyboard like following

```
<Storyboard x:Name="OpenStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid" x:Name="mOpenAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.095"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="CloseStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Duration="00:00:00.1" x:Name="mCloseAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="0.095"/>
</Storyboard>
```

OK, here comes the question, is it possible to use the animations defined in the Storyboards with the GridView items? What I want is:
When user clicks on the mOpenDetailButton button, OpenStoryboard will be played, and the ScaleY value of grid changes with it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I found you post the same issue in [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/7002/is-there-a-way-to-use-storyboard-with-listviewgrid.html) and have replied to you, you can check it.

Comment: Hi Faywang, thanks for replying. I think better to reply here with the code sample. Yes,  "grid" actually means  "myGrid", sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the Storyboard in the StackPanel inside DataTemplate and define a RenderTransform on the your myGrid as the target object of StackPanel. In this case, it simplifies the specification of target object and more convenient to get Storyboard in code-behind and play it. For example:

.xaml:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ExampleItems, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="mDataGridView">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Background="OrangeRed" x:Name="rootPanel">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="OpenStoryboard">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform" >
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.095"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Grid Width="100" Height="50" Background="Red" x:Name="myGrid">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform
                            x:Name="transform"
                            ScaleX="1" ScaleY="0" />
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                </Grid>

                <Button x:Name="mOpenDetailButton" Content="Mybutton" Click="mOpenDetailButton_Click" Margin="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

.cs:

First, get its parent panle(StackPanel) via the button, then get its Storyboard animation and play it.

```
private void mOpenDetailButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement mybutton = sender as UIElement;
    StackPanel stackPanel = FindParent<StackPanel>(mybutton);
    object storyvalue = null;
    stackPanel?.Resources.TryGetValue("OpenStoryboard", out storyvalue);
    Storyboard storyboard = value as Storyboard;
    storyboard?.Begin();
}

public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject element)
            where T : DependencyObject
{
    while (element != null)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
        T candidate = parent as T;
        if (candidate != null)
        {
            return candidate;
        }
        element = parent;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I was away for other works. And this solution works for me. Thank you Faywang.